# Sequelize belongs to many get both relations in one query

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I have belongs to many associations of the model User and Project. What is the simplest way, given a user id, query such that we have all projects that a user has, and all users of each project? My current method is quite complicated and involves two separate queries followed by parsing with Javascript. I think I'm missing some important step which could simplify the whole process. Below is the REST API response which I hope to return to the end user.

```
{
    "user_id": "wru09asf",
    "projects": [
        {
            "id": "project_id",
            "content": "Final Year Project",
            "users": [
                {
                    "id": "user_id",
                    "role": "Creator"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Currently I'm doing

```
// first function, get all projects
User.findById(user_id).then(function(user) {
    user.getProjects({

    });
});


// second function, get all users of each project returned

for each project returned, do
   Project.findById(project_id).then(function(project) {
       project.getUsers();
   });

// third function
Combine the two responses using Javascript to get the final API response.
```

Sequelize models:

```
//User (all models are underscored named)
sequelize.define('users', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        password: DataTypes.STRING,
        salt: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true
        }
    });
// Project
sequelize.define('projects', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        content: DataTypes.TEXT
    });
// UserProject
sequelize.define('user_project', {
        role: DataTypes.STRING
    });
```

Relations:

```
User.belongsToMany(Project, {through: UserProject});
Project.belongsToMany(User, {through: UserProject});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a [join](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#relations-associations):

```
User.findAll({
  where: {
    id: user_id
  },
  include: [Project]
}).then(function(user) {

});
```

Comment: I believe it is include*

Answer (score 0):

user.getProjects()

```
User.findById(1).then(function(user){
    user.getProjects().then(function(projects){
        console.log(projects);
    },function(err){
        console.log(err);
    })

},function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```